# Does a train that moves at relativistic speed and then decelerates to zero speed, seem to expand to an observer at rest near the tracks?

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, observers

A train is moving with a relativistic speed, according to an observer at rest near the tracks.  To this observer, the train seems contracted in the direction of motion.

Then, the train decelerates (all parts simultaneously, as seen by the observer at rest) until it has come to a full stop. The train will retain its proper length according to the observer watching near the tracks.

Does this mean the observer sees the train expanding in size when decelerating?